# React-pdf show image from base64 data string

Tags: react-pdf

where can I show a image with base64 on my react pdf ?

```
export const fileBase64 = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAYkAAAE+CAYAAAB4EuxwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAERlWElmTU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAABiaADAAQAAAABAAABPgAAAACiwVObAAAz0UlEQVR4Ae2dB9QURdaGL4LkJIKCIpIElSgiSUEkqKAgi7CoqCAo7K7uiglMv654xHiEdVUUBFdkxRyQJAoCCgoYQFSySBAkI0kBlX/eXrvpme6e6fmmZ6aq+61z5pvu6uqqW8/tb25XulXocCwIAwmQAAmQAAm4EDjKJY5RJEACJEACJGAQoJHgg0ACJEACJOBJgEbCEw0vkAAJkAAJ0EjwGSABEiABEvAkQCPhiYYXSIAESIAEaCT4DJAACZAACXgSoJHwRMMLJEACJEACNBJ8BkiABEiABDwJ0Eh4ouEFEiABEiABGgk+AyRAAiRAAp4EaCQ80fACCZAACZAAjQSfARIgARIgAU8CNBKeaHiBBEiABEiARoLPAAmQAAmQgCcBGglPNLwQJgL79+8XfBhIgATSI0AjkR4vptaMwJYtW6Rfv35SqlQp43PzzTcL4hhIgAT8ESjETYf8gWIqPQkUKlTIIfhNN90kjz/+uCOeESRAAk4CNBJOJowJCYELLrhApk+f7lqbffv2ScmSJV2vMZIESOAIAXY3HWHBoxARuO222zwNRIiqyaqQQNYJsCWRdcQsINcERo0aJQMHDkxaLLd2T4qHF0nAIkAjYaHgQRgI7N69W8qVK5e0KqtXr5aaNWsmTcOLJEAC/yPA7iY+CaEh8PPPP6c0EG3btqWBCI3GWZFcEKCRyAVllpF1AsuWLfM1EP3www9nXRYWQAJhIkAjESZtRrQuY8eOldNOO81X7Zs1a+YrHRORAAn8j0ARgiABXQkcOHBA6tatK2vXrvVVhR07dvhKx0QkQAJHCLAlcYQFjzQiMG/ePClevLhvAzF48GA55phjNKohRSUBNQhwdpMaeqAUaRCoV6+efPvtt447ChcuLL/99psjHhGHDh2SIkXYcHaFw0gSSEKALYkkcHhJLQIffvihwM2Gm4GApO3bt/cUGAaEgQRIIH0CNBLpM+MdOSawc+dOY+ZSu3btXEvu0qWL/Prrr4LprV7h999/97rEeBIggSQEaCSSwOGl/BLAD/8999wjFSpUEKyBcAuzZs2SiRMnCloKl19+uVsSI44rrD3R8AIJJCXAMYmkeHgxXwQmT54sF198sWfxNWrUkJUrVxrGwUwEQ3DUUe7vPTQSJiV+k0B6BDiSlx4vps4yAbjMqF27dtJS1qxZI9WrV3ekcXML7kjECBIggbQIuL92pZUFE5NA5gTgc6ls2bJJDcScOXMELQI3A5G5BMyBBEjAjQCNhBsVxuWMAMYaGjdubPhc2rNnj6PcWrVqyYsvvmgYh9atWzuuM4IESCC7BNjdlF2+zN2DANYztGzZUhYuXOiRQuS5556Tvn37xo07eCaOXUg27oBr7I5KRo/XSMCdAI2EOxfGZonAwYMHBS2CBQsWeJbQtWtXefPNN30bBzMjGgmTBL9JIDgCNBLBsWROSQhgzAHbiX766adJUols377dmPKaNBEvkgAJ5IwAxyRyhjqaBa1bt05OPfVUY8whmYFYtWqV0V2ENREMJEAC6hCgkVBHF6GSZPr06QK33CeffLIsX77cs24rVqwwjAMGqDMN27Zt88zCa/2E5w28QAIkYBCgkeCDEBgBrJC+7777jAFidC15DUo3atRI0P2EMYRTTjklsPIxjsFAAiQQLAGOSQTLM5K5YQHcOeecIz/++GPS+j/66KNy0003pT0gnTRT28UxY8bYznhIAiQQBAG2JIKgGME8MIX1+uuvN1oNWCHtZSAuvPBCmTJlitFquPXWW7NmIKACbGHqFu688063aMaRAAn4IMCWhA9ITHKEQCqfSmZKdClNmjRJqlatakZl/btTp07y2muvOco5/vjjHXGMIAES8EeADv78cYp0KjjSw6I27AaXKsATK7p9SpQokSpp4NfRkvDa63rXrl3GDKvAC2WGJBByAuxuCrmCC1q9/fv3y7333mt0J9WpUyelgRg9erTRpfTSSy/lxUCgnphqC/9PbqF8+fJy4oknSrIZUG73MY4Eok6ARiLqT4Ct/tiY5/XXXxeMI5QqVUqGDh1qu+o8xI/y5s2bDeNw7bXXOhPkIWb+/PmepW7cuFEqVaokzZs3l48++sgzHS+QAAkcIUAjcYRFZI+++OILYz0DNu7p2bOnvPfee54sTjjhBFm0aJFhGJYuXSrHHXecZ9p8XIDhOv/885MWDZcgbdq0MVpJjz32WNK0+biI1s4ll1wiZ555ptGa27p1az7EYJkkYBDgmEREH4QNGzYYbjK89ou2Y8FCt1dffVWaNGlij1b2GOsvCrJ4btOmTVK5cuW81AvjPdie9cCBA47yr7vuOhk1apQjnhEkkAsCNBK5oKxIGYcOHZL+/fsbrrdTiYR9o6+44grp1auX8cadKr2K1zt27CgffPBB2qLBGHbu3FkaNGhg7F1Rrlw5Yw/tLVu2yA8//CB4s4ejwqOPPtpoSWERIc7REitZsqTRpYUWF1yMYIwE3md/+eUX2bFjh+zdu1e++uorQwfvv/++L9nQWkO3HgMJ5IMAjUQ+qOe4zKefftpY0+Cn2BtuuEGGDRsmZcqU8ZNc+TQwjOi6mTp1qvKyegk4YMAAefbZZ70uM54EskqARiKrePOTORa6YZbR1Vdf7VuAd955R+CiO8xh9uzZ0rZtW62qiBbd2LFjpWLFilrJTWHDQ4BGIiS6RDfGE088IXfddZfvGmGl9Oeff+45bdR3RpolhDdabHikchg8eLA8+OCDBRpbUblelE0/AjQS+unMkBh94FjRPG3aNJk4cWJafdbPPPOMDBw4UNOaByc23JjDS60qYfjw4fLXv/5VihUrpopIlIMEhEZCk4cAfevoQrrllluMjXnSFRsrpp988klj/UO690YhPfh+/fXXAtfl2NsCW6d+//33nlWvWbOmwA0IBrnRvYeBZTg6nDlzpsD4uAWkRxdgvXr1jO4jzKTilqpupBinEgEaiT+0gYVkGNzcs2ePwNdPtWrVBDNUihcvbv0j4+0dC7IwVXLfvn1GPGavHHPMMYbLBxwH8RaIcvBjhTdL9EcXNDzyyCOCgeh8uMgoqMy8jwRIQC0CdPAX0wcMBN4IFy9enBXtNG3a1FiT0LBhQ8M1BIxJlSpVBK4vsPIX+y6MGzdOdu7cWeDyYQgwbfO2224zNvvhG2qBUfJGEiABGwG2JGIw/Ho2tXFT5hDuuu+//36jNaOMUBSEBEggNATYktBQldi4B7OYjj32WA2lp8gkQAI6EWBLIqatbHc3BfFAjBgxwhhfwKpeBhIgARLIFQEaiT9Iw1Cg2+ntt9/OaLA4U8Vhs57u3btLt27dpH79+pwnnylQ3k8CJJARARqJFPiwLecDDzxgTB9NkdT3Zbi8gMO8Fi1aGO4v2DrwjY4JSYAEckyARiJN4HDUBlfZmAuPefT4YNUy3E97Bfje6dOnjzGDClNqGUiABEhAFwI0ErpoinKSAAmQQB4IcNOhPEBnkSRAAiSgCwEaCV00RTlJgARIIA8EaCTyAJ1FkgAJkIAuBGgkdNEU5SQBEiCBPBCgkcgDdBZJAiRAAroQoJHQRVOUkwRIgATyQIBGIg/QWSQJkAAJ6EKARkIXTVFOEiABEsgDARqJPEBnkSRAAiSgCwEaCV00RTlJgARIIA8EaCTyAJ1FkgAJkIAuBLjpkC6aopwkoBmB+fPnywcffCBFihQxtu9t3LixZjWguCBAB398DkiABAIlsG3bNunRo4fMnj3byveoo46SYcOGyZAhQ6w4HuhBgEZCDz1RShLQhsAVV1whEyZMcMhbqFAhWbhwoZx55pmOa4xQlwCNhLq6oWQkoB0B7LdSqlQpY0tgN+EvueQSY/dHt2uMU5MAjYSaeqFUJKAlgS+//NLYXMtL+KJFi8qBAwe8LjNeQQKc3aSgUigSCehKYN68eUlFP3jwYNLrvKgeARoJ9XRCiUhAWwKbN2/WVnYK7k6ARsKdC2NJgAQKQGD9+vUFuIu3qEyARkJl7VA2EtCMwNFHH62ZxBQ3FQEaiVSEeJ0ESMA3gdKlS/tOy4R6EKCR0ENPlJIEtCCAVdbJgn2BXbJ0vKYOAU6BVUcXlIQEtCeABXPJAmY3sUsqGSH1rrEloZ5OKBEJaElg+/btKeX+9ddfU6ZhArUI0EiopQ9KQwLaErjrrrtSyl64cOGUaZhALQLsblJLH5SGBLQlkKqrCRVDS4KGQi8VsyWhl74oLQkoSeD777/3JRcNhC9MSiViS0IpdVAYEtCTQLFixcSPy43Dhw/rWcEIS82WRISVz6qTQBAE0IVkNxBnn312ENkyD0UI0EgoogiKQQK6EjjvvPPiRJ82bVrcOU/0JkAjobf+KD0J5JUApr1+/PHHlgw9e/YUrrq2cITigEYiFGpkJUggPwTatWsXV/DLL79snLt1OfXq1SsuLU/0IEAjoYeeKCUJKEfgq6++EnzMgG4m7GWNUK1aNTPa+l6zZo11zAN9CNBI6KMrSkoCyhD4/fffpVWrVpY8jRs3lgsuuMA6L1++vHVsHixYsMA85LdGBGgkNFIWRSUBVQi89tprsm/fPkucuXPnWsc4KFOmTNw5T/QlQCOhr+4oOQnkhQD2qL722mutsseNGyclS5a0znFQuXLluHOe6EuARkJf3VFyEsgLgeuvv1727t1rlN2hQwfp3bu3Q45atWo54hihJwGuuNZTb5SaBPJCYPny5XLqqadaZWMwunr16ta5ebB69WqpXbu2eWp903eThUKbA7YktFEVBSWB/BOwGwh0ObkZCEjpFb9///78V4ISpEWARiItXExMAtElMGrUqLjKjxw5Mu7cfuLlyG/Lli32ZDzWgACNhAZKoogkkG8CP/30kwwcONASY+bMmVKkSBHr3O/B5s2b/SZlOkUI0EgoogiKQQIqE7B3H2FQOtFfk5vsbtuU7tixwy0p4xQmQCOhsHIoGgmoQAArqXft2mWJ8s0331jHyQ7uvPNOx2VMn2XQiwCNhF76orQkkFMCWFndqVMnq8wJEyYI9o7wE04//XRHsiVLljjiGKE2ARoJtfVD6UggrwQSF8VddtllvuVxc80xf/583/czoRoEaCTU0AOlIAHlCEyZMkW2bt1qyZXu9FU3I/H+++9b+fFADwI0EnroiVKSQE4JYDbTRRddZJU5Y8YMKVGihHXu58DNf9Nvv/3m51amUYgAjYRCyqAoJKAKAXsroFu3bpK4b4QfOdM1Kn7yZJrcE6CRyD1zlkgCShN4+OGH4+R766234s79nrhNgfV7L9OpQ4C+m9TRBSUhgbwTwCZCjRo1suTAmETFihWt83QOdu7cKRUqVHDccvjwYUccI9QlwJaEurqhZCSQUwLw7Go3ENOnTy+wgYDg5cqVy6n8LCw7BGgkssOVuZKAVgTwdt++fXtL5qFDh0rHjh2t84IcmFuZFuRe3qMOAXY3qaMLSkICeSMwevRoGTBggFE+jANaEUGEQoUKObJhd5MDidIRNBJKq4fCkUD2Caxdu1ZM30x4+4frjII473OTFIPX2EPCHjIZ57Dnw+PcEGB3U244sxQSUJLAoUOH4rqVVq1aFZiBQIUff/xxR703btzoiGOEugRoJNTVDSUjgawTgJuNlStXGuXAL1ONGjUCLfPcc8915Ddx4kRHHCPUJcDuJnV1Q8lIIKsEnnvuObnuuuuMMtq0aSOzZs0StzGETIT4+eefpWTJko4sOC7hQKJsBI2EsqqhYCSQPQILFiyQ5s2bWwXADUfZsmWt8yAP3AwPjUSQhLObF7ubsstXydzh/nny5MnGB8cM0SKwe/fuOAOxfPnyrBkIL7Jr1qzxusR4xQjQSCimkGyLA6PQpEkTufjii40Pjmkosk1drfzti9yefvppqVOnTlYFvPHGGx352xftOS4yQikC7G5SSh3ZF2bSpEnSpUuXuIIQZ/f4GXeRJ6Ei0KNHD3njjTeMOuGHetGiRVmvH1oudsNkFsguJ5OE2t9sSaitn8Clc/Pnj2mQDOEnMH78eMtAoLaffPJJTirtNdbBqbA5wZ9xITQSGSPUKwOMRSSGSpUqJUbxPGQEvv/+e7nqqqusWuE8l6680YJJDEOGDEmM4rmCBNjdpKBSsimS20wTeOu07x+QzfKZd+4JYEe5UqVKWQW/8MILcvXVV1vnuTg4ePCg697Y7HLKBf3MyqCRyIyfdne7GQnsFkZnbNqp0rfAdp2feeaZ8tlnn/m+N8iEdjnMfGkkTBLqfrO7SV3d5EwyGoicoc55QX369Ikrc+HChXHnuTy59957HcUtXbrUEccItQjQSKilj6xKg24lhugQeP3112XcuHFWhX/88cfAV1Rbmfs4+POf/+xIhcF0BrUJsLtJbf0EKt3s2bOlbdu2jjzZ5Hcg0T4Ci9Vq1qxp1WPGjBkF2qfayiCAAzxnbq1WPn8BwM1iFmxJZBGuall//PHHDpFatmzpiGOE3gT27dsXZyBuuummvBsIEHUbk9CbdDSkp5GIhp6NWj7//POO2l544YWOOEboSwCTEEqXLm1VoGrVqq7uuq0EChywG1QBJSQRgUYiCZywXVq9erWjSq1bt3bEMUJfAnanfajF+vXrlaqM6XXWLtSLL75oP+WxYgQ4JqGYQrIpjltzf9u2bXLsscdms1jmnSMCmD2EvanNAHcYZcqUMU+V+P70008lsYuzWLFi8ssvvyghH4VwEqCRcDIJbYybkeCgYTjUjZX0cNpoBmxJWq1aNfNUmW8uqlNGFb4FYXeTb1R6J8RbJUM4CaxYsSLOQHz44YdKGgjQL1q0aDiVEOJa0UiEWLn2quVrla1dBh4HT2Dv3r1St25dK+NXXnnFdZqzlUDRA3R7MqhJgEZCTb0ELtVLL70UeJ7MML8EsDWofcwB+za4LVjLr5TO0gcMGOCInDlzpiMuTBE6e1qmkQjTk5ikLmPGjHFcdVtY50jECCUJ4Efn9NNPt2Q7//zzZfjw4da5ygedO3d2iPd///d/jjjdIrZu3SpvvvmmXHrppcaaEIwBmh90s5177rny3Xff6VYtKaKdxBQ4MAKJfn0Cy5gZZZUAJhtcdtllAnffCM2aNZP33nvPONbhD+RNDBhX0SVgLcqSJUtkwoQJArm/+OILWbduXUrx58yZY6xZefLJJ1OmVSkBjYRK2sixLG3atMlxiSwuCAKPPvqo8caKvDCDaf78+UFkm7M8qlSp4loWWkdHH32067V8RmJ67qhRo8RtG9Z05dJx7IVTYNPVsqbp3aa/0kW4fsqED6YOHToYgsMPEn7AVPxhTUXW7Xl87LHH5JZbbkl1a9avr1q1St566y0ZPHhw4GVhnUjigsfACwk4QxqJgIGqmB1mwNgHOE0ZuUbCJKHHN7o27DOZtm/fLhUqVNBD+AQp69SpIytXrkyIFcn0mfz9998FP/JoXU2ZMkVefvllRxmJETCyGJ9z29o3Ma3bOfbv/umnn4xLDRo0kKZNm0q9evWkevXqxkJVbPiEMjCGpOMUYBoJN62HLA59pthsJjFk+g+ZmB/Ps0cAbr5POukk+fXXX41C8ANbu3bt7BWY5Zw///xz48c0sZh0nkmknTt3rvTt21d++OGHnK7aHjhwoHTv3t1oFcBIhDlwTCLM2v2jbrr1WUdAJWlVES1Bez8+3nh1NhCovNtLC+Lxw2/vioJRhANA7IuB7igYy1yHhg0byj333CNdu3bVsmsvU140EpkS1OD+gjajNaha6EXEuJG9q/D222+3xiTCWPl58+YZXUS5ngEEw9SxY0dp1aqV9bHvCx5G1n7rxO4mv6Q0TlekSBHBj409XHnllULvm3Yi6h1DZ+jDRj87QosWLYzuFbeNe9STPrVEPXv2FOyel++AsQu4zLe3YPItk0rlczGdStrIkiyJBgLFtG/fPkulMdsgCMAR3nHHHWcZCOSJmU1hMRCoz0UXXYSvnAdwxSwjdG3h06lTJxqIJFpgd1MSOGG+VL9+/TBXT/u6YZbMjh07rHpgJlPJkiWt8zAcZLMVgdbzBRdcIFiJji4kzDYqUaJEGLDlvA40EjlHrkaBmCnDoCaBLl26GCt5Tekwk0nXqa5mHRK/sUsi3JsHEeCv6s477xQY1jC1tIJgE0QeHJMIgqLiebj1tR44cEDLOduKo85YPOxHPWLECCsf/JC6+TqyEmh44LVux09VjjnmGGOmE8YQ0FrIJGCF9yeffCLPPfecseVrjx49rLUMaHUUL17c6IZClxT+X7Zs2WK4Qtm0aZORHt1UUTBKNBKZPGUa3AtPoW7dFHjwGdQi8NBDD8kdd9xhCXX//ffL3XffbZ2H5QA70WHMJVVANxEWw2H6b6YGwV4WZvuhGyrT0KhRI8NvU9gNBQeuM31SFL/fXAmquJiRF2/8+PFxBgI/kGE0EHBKmMpAYPorXmKwUA7dokEZCLQa0KoOwkDggV28eLFMnTo19M8ujUTIVbx///6Q11D/6uHN9qqrroqryOzZs+POw3JSo0aNlFXBIH3Q4brrrjMGsIPONwr50UiEXMvwY8OgLgG4TEl8s8WbdlBvzyrV/O2333aIY9+X27yI/v8gQ69evYxxhyDzRF7obsK4RNgDjUTINbx+/XpHDe1O4hwXGZEzApi1lOieAm4ndPTqmgrarl275O9//3tcMqzVOf744+PicPLxxx874goSgfVBt956q7z66qsFud3zniuuuELeeeedSIxHAEJm0wM8MfKCKgTg9yYxYP44Q34JYIYMPKHaA/q43X407Wl0PcaubBs2bIgTHz+0gwYNiovDyYIFCxxx6UbguQ9i2jA25sLYkO6+stLlZ09PI2GnEcLjWbNmOWoFj5kM+SOAH7ATTjghTgBsewlHcmEMTz31lHz11VdxVZs0aZLAN5Lb3s/YIyOT8PXXXxtrJvzkgYkdZcuWNdzWwHDDDQq6+oIwMH7K1yENu5t00FIGMroZhDfeeCODHHlrJgR2797t+AF64IEH5E9/+lMm2Sp7L2Yz3XDDDXHyYUq26ZID3VBBBmwpikV1qQK2e8UMKhgIhMKFC0vVqlUNVyg0EPH0aCTiefg6g8M1LHLCx3S+5uvGPCTC9pYMahDAIrLEvQeuueYaY7WwGhIGKwV+hN1mM9lfXPD2HlT417/+JRgvSBbw/4BFcYmTBZLdE/lrMUUypEEgNhh2ODarASvRjE/FihUPI07VENvcxZLVlBnfY8aMUVXkUMoV2xfBoYfYbmihrKtZqdigvKPON998s3nZ+I7t1uZIg+cz3fDuu++65mN/5ocMGXIYemBIjwBXXMeeonQCWg+J0/bgVXLz5s3pZJPTtG5uOSBA7FHJqRxRLQxTWrHK2B7whv3dd9/Zo0J1jLGw8847z1GnxGfurLPOks8++yxlOkcCWwQ41qpVyxbjPMSYT1i79Jy1DTaG3U0B8ETzNfaWEkBO2ckCHjDdgupdZW4y6xaHaZiJBgJ93qtXr9atKr7lxW5ybgbiyy+/dOQRa4k74vDS5TegrFQGYunSpTQQfoG6pKORcIGSLMpr8cwjjzwiCxcuTHZr3q5hk3e3EAWXAm71zlWc26K4SpUqCVYUe7XuciVbNstxW+dRunRpady4saNYtzEzTJf1E9AqcSvLfi88Dpx66qn2KB6nSYDdTWkCQ/KtW7casyDcbsXgpGrbHm7btk3w45QY4FHTvmdB4nWeZ0YAjt/s3Ss4x5tvmA0EWgtNmjRxgMNUV7dV5OhqQpeTPWBDoObNm9ujHMfID9NVvQJkQN5hZu1V96Dj2ZIoAFH84MJjp1vAG5Nqwa1JDxndFtqpJruO8sAwYGql3UBUrlzZmIsf9h8tNwOBFc9uBgK6bdq0qbEqGi9WcM8NV+mpDATWNiQzELFBbIlN2KCBCOifhy2JDEB6/cOjj1Q1n0lespqLiTLAwFttBPCGe9ppp8WNOWDh3Lp164y5+LakoTscNmyY3HXXXY562Y2l4+IfEXv27DGOypQp45XEiEfL99hjj3VNAyOD8UEVX9RcBdYkki2JDBTl5a0Sg5ItW7ZUag3F448/7lpTLD5iCIYAxiCwkMs+KI0+d6wLwGKtMAd0o7kZCL+tVRiHVAYCjv+8DATYYvyBBiL4p4xGIgOmmKVy9tlnu+aAflV0MWCFrQohcdWrKdNf/vIX85DfGRCAgWjWrJksX77cyiW2BkDWrl1rnYf5wO05GjhwoJQvXz6wamOnOK/gp7XidS/jkxNgd1NyPimvYhppsrdErLCFV8v69eunzCvbCby6nPgPlhl5GIg2bdrI/PnzrYxgIOCwz6sv3koYggOv7Ugx/TeoXdu8nl3gw+6LyQxICBDntQpsSWSIH/8E9h+HxOzQ548uiBkzZiReyvk5NoxnCJYADARcPNifAUz1xCyfKBgI0GzdurUDKp73oAxEMg+sGKOggXDgDzYi9hbJEACBSy+9NKVbgG7dugVQUsGzgPuQ2NPj+MT6cgueaYTvBLcrr7wyjmdsZs7hWN95ZKjEjGNc/fF8xdydB1b/2IZBjvzNZzjm9ymwcpiRNwF2NwVkc82VtfhOFdasWSPVq1dPlSwr192a7XgLRn86g38CGGuCDu0Ds1gENn369KTTM/2XoH5KtKISV5ND6mXLlkkQG1sNHjxYHn30UVcQ3377rTGLzPUiIwMlwO6mgHBiXAK7iiXuE+CWPfz2mK6S3a5nM85t8ZwKXWHZrHPQeYMhxprsBiLWooiUgQBTN4+rnTt3DsRA3H///Z4GAntTYJoxQ24IsCURMOd0NjzBgis88CeffHLAUiTPDtNzMfvKDHgDhkM2htQEYBgS9xvADJ6NGzcai8FS5xCOFIsWLZIzzjjDURnsH5Hp89y/f38ZO3asI29EYPZY4o5+rgkZGRgBGonAUB7JCN1JNWvWPBLh4wjGxcsRn4/b00oS632MG1TEwB9miDAkJ4CFWm7bi0ZxQaJbtyXo4dkqaMBaC6y8RjeWW4Cn5XSc/7nlwbj0CbC7KX1mKe9Ad1K66yMwRRb/eB9++GHK/DNNgHLmzZtnZZPpdpFWRiE+wBusm4HAgkpzd7MQVz+ual5dpTNnzoxLl84JWiBw1udmINByw1gfDUQ6RINLSyMRHMu4nLB6FG9VTz75ZFx8qpN27doZxqJ3796GM7hU6Qt6HV1OsQ1gjLLQXYLVrAzuBD766CNXT6IwEIldT+45hCcWz8mUKVNcK+TmHtw1YULkE0884bqDHZINGjTI8Job1HTahKJ56oeA98QnXgmSwAcffOA5lS+mJ89rsS6ow7FNVYIUxcor1oKwyo2NSVjxPDhC4LXXXrMY2fUU6/o4kihCR3YG9uOnn346bQqYKmzPI/E4th1p2nnyhuAJ4G2XIccEZs+enfSfI/GfJda8z5qEsWmGhiyxwcaslaFrxkOHDnXV04oVK3StUkZyJ/tRTzfjBQsWuLI1n/3YXifpZsn0WSJAI5ElsH6yjfm7T/qPYv7DxMYQDsemXfrJMu00MWd0lgxRfTt2gwbDbPK3f8c2lnJLHom4hg0bujLp3r17WvXv0qWLaz4m55UrV6aVHxNnlwBnN8WezHwH+L6HX32vENtQ3nUfYK/06cabM1WweOnhhx9O9/bQpceaF7etXeGDy8uhY+gguFTIfE4SL8V+ohKjXM+TbdZl3qDipl2mbFH95sC1ApqHEcA/GgYFMVBnD5hK67Xq1J4uk2Ns9IKALVijHDDLCz+EbgYCCw6jbCAweJ9JgIFNNjvp1ltvNf4HVNvVMZM6h+VetiQU1iTm5Sf7xwpKdKwUr1KlipHdnDlzXB22BVWWqvlgFbXXXgWYlty2bVtVRc+JXF6tCOyVkcrLwG233SaPPfaYp5xc/+CJRokLNBJKqCH/Qpg/AvC4GesTzr9AOZRgyZIlEutvdy0RXYFuW3K6Jg5xpPl8JFYxWVcTdptLtoYEXZvo4mRQmwC7m9TWT86k+8c//mGUhW1XsQVnVMLrr7/uaSCwYRANhMhLL73k+ji47URnJoTbl2QGAuMTNBAmLcW/szsuztx1IYCZTbFH1fjEugd0ETsjOW+88Uarzmbdze9szSbLSOA83RxzpufKKfYy4SrRgAEDXNOD7X333ed6DyPVJcDuptiTy/A/AvYuhdgjG1os8FOF2WRwN+0WMHBtZ+GWJipxsWnactZZZzmqW7JkSdm3b19cvNcOdWYiOJGEM0kGvQiwu0kvfWVV2nfffdfKf+TIkdZxmA4wSI8fODcD0adPH2NmEw3EEY27GQhcHTFixJFEsaNp06YJXNF4BQxw00B40VE7ni0JtfWTc+nsP5CYEuq2qUzOhQqoQGwp6jXGEHO/IT169AiopHBkA99UFStWdK0MHPHBIR8CWl5FixY1nPC5JcYAdunSpd0uMU4DAmxJaKCkXIo4ceJEq7jLL7/cOtb94Pnnn/c0EBisp4Fwarhnz57OyD9iTAOB023btrmuLUGLDe6/aSA8MWpxgS0JLdSUWyHtrQlsitSgQYPcChBgaXjjPeWUU2TdunWuudrfiF0TRDjS/hzYMVStWlXWr19vj5KYaw556623rLgxY8ZIv379rHMe6EuALQl9dZc1yWMO7Ky8sX5A1w2JPvnkE6O7zM1A4AcMg/P2N2Kr0jxISqBjx46O66+88orgM3z4cMO1Nw2EA5G2EWxJaKu67Ap+xx13yEMPPWQUcvvtt8uDDz6Y3QIDzB1dHC1atBAshEsM6DtH15Pb/syJaaN+7tWSAJcwz36Lut4T608jkUiE5wYB7ASGbhpsxYqgi7sOr72XjUpoVA9T3nx+YwaT6dcrUQ520yUSCe85jUR4dZtxzWI+/6V58+ZWPvv375cSJUpY5yodYIYNvLcmC7ncRzyZHLpcgyHwmt0GX1a52GpXF1ZhlpNjEmHWboZ1a9asWVy3DGarqNjNAO+1qQwE3EDEdvnLkEi0bkfXXGzvB9dKY2Fc1Hx8uYKIQCRbEhFQciZVROvB7r75nHPOkUzdRmcij/1ezLxq1KiRPcr1GCuDYeAY0iewe/duKVeunOeNsU2rBO7sGcJLgC2J8Oo2kJrhx3Xx4sVWXtgXAIYiny0KuPU+6aSTUhoIzMyCnDQQlvrSPoCTPvvU1sQMatWqJS+88EJiNM9DRIBGIkTKzFZV8GP773//28p+7ty5ctRRRwlW0uYyYNzh2muvNfZ92LBhQ9KiY3skxxm3pIl5MSmBbt26Sf/+/T3T9O3bV1q1auV5nRf0JsDuJr31l1PpsQIXrrXtIRd7AqA1MHr0aMO19E8//WQv3nGMgfVdu3YZbiIcFxmREQGsfcD04WQBs+LwAsEQHgI0EuHRZU5qgvUFEyZMcJSFN/cLL7zQEZ9pxL333itDhw71lQ32f6hWrZqvtExUMALYW6J3795Jb6ahSIpHu4s0EtqpLP8Cjx8/Xq666iqHIHCeh5ZFhw4dHNfSiYCHVuSFPb/9BOw/3a5dOz9JmSYAAmjNlS9fPmlONBRJ8Wh1kUZCK3WpIyzGBDB47BW6du0qV155peE+GmMJGADFAPLxxx8vlStXtqasoitp2bJl8uabb8rdd9/tlZ1rPN5qw+SE0LWSCkeOGjVKBg4c6CrhpEmT5KKLLnK9xki9CNBI6KUv5aQdNGiQMagNQ5CrADchDzzwAPu+cwU8STkbN26UE0880ZGCRsKBRNsIGgltVaeO4FjJnCtPsWjBuP0oqUMjepJgT3QsvDMD1q588cUXNOImEM2/OQ1BcwWqIH79+vWNDWew8jlbAesz0DVFA5EtwgXPF550MQaB1gM+NBAFZ6ninWxJqKgVzWWaN2+e/O1vf8t4nUKbNm2MKbeVKlXSnAjFJwF9CdBI6Ks7bSSH6250Sc2cOVOGDRtm7DeQKHz79u3lkksuERgGP642Eu/nOQmQQHYI0EhkhytzJQESIIFQEOCYRCjUyEqQAAmQQHYI0EhkhytzJQESIIFQEKCRCIUaWQkSIAESyA4BGonscGWuJEACJBAKAkVCUQtWQnkCWONghkKFCpmH/CYBElCcAFsSiitIV/HgnG/kyJECg4AP3EebH5wn28hG1zpTbhIIIwFOgQ2jVhWo08033yzDhw9PKgm2H82VO4+kgvAiCZCAJwG2JDzR8EImBJ555pmUt9t3u0uZmAlIgATyQoAtibxgD3+hcAv+888/+6pohQoVjI1sOnfuLHXr1pUaNWr4uo+JSIAEsk+ARiL7jCNZgp/uplRgTjjhBIHhwIZCLVu2NJz7wZkcAwmQQO4I0EjkjnWkSsLA9dixYw1Hf9moeMWKFQVbqfbq1cvYxa548eLZKIZ5kkDkCdBIRP4RyA0Arymw2Kxo1apVxmfJkiWG19fPPvuswEJVqVJF+vXrJ126dJGGDRtKiRIlCpwXbyQBEhChkeBToCQB7E+AvZRhMCZPnizjxo2TXbt2FUhWbLN63nnnGYYDs6mqV68uxYoVK1BevIkEokaARiJqGg9BfeF6fPXq1TJ16lRjvcWcOXN81wprNMxWDQbML730Ujn77LPljDPOkHr16ll7b/vOkAlJIOQEaCRCruCoVW/Pnj2ycuVKWbhwoUybNs3YKQ1GJd3QvHlz6dGjh3Tq1Enq1KkjHDBPlyDTh4UAjURYNMl6JCXwyy+/yNq1aw0DgtXeaH1gLCTdgK1aBw0aJF27dhXumJcuPabXkQCNhI5ao8yBEdi/f79gu9X33ntP/vvf/8qmTZvSzvvkk0+WG264wTAcaHUwkECYCNBIhEmbrEsgBDBmsWbNGmPAHK5FcJxuaNq0qdFdhTEPGBF2V6VLkOlVIUAjoYomKIfyBLCCfMaMGfKf//xH3njjjbTkhXNDjG9069ZNmjVrJqeccgqn56ZFkInzRYBGIl/kWW4oCGCqLsY2pkyZIhMmTDAGzNOpGFaV9+3bV8466yw555xzBIsEGUhAJQI0Eippg7KEhsDOnTtl/vz58sknn8j48ePlu+++S6tuaG1gRTlaHuiuYiCBfBGgkcgXeZYbOQKYYbVixQrBynIsDpw+fXpaDIoUKSL33XefXH311VK1atW07mViEigoARqJgpLjfSQQAAEYjq+//tpobWCsA6vM0wm1a9eW22+/XXr27Clly5ZN51amJQFfBGgkfGFiIhLIHQF0VWEh4FNPPSVz585Nu+Du3bvLNddcI23atKHhSJseb0gkQCORSITnJKAggaVLlxo7/Y0ePTpt6eCKpE+fPnL55ZdLixYtpEyZMsaWsmlnxBsiSYBGIpJqZ6V1J4BFgFgAOHToUFm0aFHa1YG3XOzVgQ8cIMJvFTaKYiCBRAI0EolEeE4CmhKAl1xMxcXKcXxnElq1amVs9tS6dWtp1KiR4YIEaz0YokeARiJ6OmeNI0QAA+MfffSR8cFCQLggCSJgp0DMsjr//PONKbqFCxcOIlvmoSABGgkFlUKRSCDbBDAVF+Mcs2bNkhEjRgRaHJwfYo0HDAm6sjAmwqAvARoJfXVHyUkgMAIY48AeHc8++6wxqyqwjG0ZoQsLiwObNGliGJCiRYsK1n4wqE2ARkJt/VA6Esgbga1bt8qLL75orMM4dOhQ3uTANrQXX3yxtG3bVk477TQ5/vjj6TAxh9qgkcghbBZFAjoTMPcjHzlyZOBdVAXl0r9/f2N6L/xesVuroBST30cjkZwPr5IACaQgAO+42IscmzmNHTs27VXjKbL3fRldV3CWOGTIEKlRowa3ovVNLnlCGonkfHiVBEggAwLbtm2Tb775xjAi2A1w4sSJGeSW/q0wFpMnTza6qdK/m3eAAI0En4OMCKALYurUqcYPwfr16w1X2fB+aobSpUvL3r17zVNf3w0aNJDevXtLhw4dpG7duoI88hVQP3RjYCMiuAXHN+JwjA+uYf2AuY82NhcyryPevBf3meeYlnrgwAFrPwmsb8AgLj7o+8fHzANlIG98Iw7HBw8ejLtuXrN/ozyUjXIQX6xYMcEbP8rGOfLAOa4jDsf79u0zdGXKgDjkg3shO+qGBXf4FC9e3IiHzLiOD97k4T8K+SBfswycI6/du3cbH+xDjuuo9+bNm42WB2TKZoBL9h9++CGbRYQ2bxqJ0Ko2+xXDjxZmqixevDj7hf1RQr9+/QSzZDA/Hz9IGFw1f/R27NghP/74o2zcuNFwzb1s2TLD6+q6det8y4cfPRipzz//3PhhRB2zFfDDih9LhtwQgIHleo70WdNIpM+Md/xBAM14zDrJR8Bbq/n2HnT5jRs3NgxfpUqVZMuWLUFnb+VHI2GhyMkBWkUM6RPgJOX0mfEOBQgU5B++VKlSRssHUyrxqVmzppx44onGbnDoQsFbJloS6FoJIkBGe7eRmafZvVOiRAkjSvXuJnQtoesq3e4mdFth/YVbdxO6otDthOsw+DCY4I6yoCd7lxY44bx8+fKyfft2owsMXZibNm0yuqo2bNiQsivpn//8p4mf32kSYEsiTWBMfoRAPrqb0BUEV9gYs8B8efwQmf3j5o+7+X1EUh5FlQCeUT4PmWmfRiIzfpG/G/+EQQ9cm1CxOhcurjEHvkKFCvxnN8HwmwRySIBGIoewWRQJkAAJ6EYgmM5X3WpNeUmABEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8EaCR8IWJiUiABEggmgRoJKKpd9aaBEiABHwRoJHwhYmJSIAESCCaBGgkoql31poESIAEfBGgkfCFiYlIgARIIJoEaCSiqXfWmgRIgAR8Efh/y1BfXZr9AL4AAAAASUVORK5CYII='

return (
  <Document>
    <Page style={s.body}>
      <View style={s.headerTop}>
        <View style={s.leftTop}>
          <Text style={s.small}>Sports Cars Rental &bull; Fössestraße 99A &bull; 30453 Hannover</Text>
          <Text style={s.text}>{d.renter.surname} {d.renter.lastname}</Text>
          <Text style={s.text}>{d.renter.street}</Text>
          <Text style={s.text}>{d.renter.plz} {d.renter.location}</Text>
        </View>
        <Image style={s.image} src={img} />
      </View>

      <Image
          source={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${fileBase64}`} // also tried src
          style={{height: 150, width: 150}}
        />
   
....
```

I only get a blank space nothing else I am very thankful for your help

Comment: how your Image component work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your imbedded image is wrong it should look like for HTML **iVBOR**=PNG  since the structure for a jpeg should start something like `data:image/jpeg;base64,`**/9j/...**

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,` then at end of data injection you simply need `"/>`

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
```

For React-PDF it is similar

```
<Image
style={s.image}
src="data:image/png;base64,'${fileBase64}' "/>
```

Thus result from above is

[image]

Use the demo as a playground, so here I tried using uri as a "style"

[image]

Comment: what if you don't know the file type and it might be jpeg?